# How to make paging in knockout.js?

Tags: knockout.js

I need to break into pages with 4 entries, for example.

Please see code http://pastebin.com/Et1Z9hHG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `simpleGrid` [plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html) should work for that.